# Circle page indicator - how to change fill color changing

Tags: android

I'm using **ViewPageIndicator**, specifically **CirclePageIndictor** in my Android application. The requirement is that the *fillColor* will move straight to the next circle in the indicator, without the situation like this one in the picture (the circle moves slowly and stays in the middle while paging)

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: did you find solution ? I didn't get this effect with `vpi:snap="true"` or `vpi.setSnap(true);`

Answer (score 36):

You can try this on your xml:

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        app:radius="12dp"
        app:fillColor="@color/header_bg_color"
        app:pageColor="#ffffff"
        app:strokeColor="@color/header_bg_color"/>
```

and don't forget to add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" on your layout.
E.g

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            app:radius="12dp"
            app:fillColor="@color/header_bg_color"
            app:pageColor="#ffffff"
            app:strokeColor="@color/header_bg_color"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried but still display default color any other way?

Answer (score 5):

Set the snap attribute to true.

```
vpi:snap="true"
```

or

```
vpi.setSnap(true);
```

Comment: where should i set this ? in my case indicator is not changing while i change the page, but my page content is changing.

Answer (score 3):

```
final CirclePageIndicator circleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    circleIndicator.setViewPager(_pager);
    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    circleIndicator.setFillColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    circleIndicator.setStrokeColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    circleIndicator.setStrokeWidth(1);
    circleIndicator.setRadius(6 * density);
```

Answer (score 1):

try app:snap="true"

```
 <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:snap="true"/>
```